# How to refer to a password-protected FTP address in Python (Pandas)?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, ftp

I'm using Python (Pandas) to parse JSON files into dataframes, which I'm then using to update SQL tables on a MySQL server. The JSON files in question are provided to me in the form of an FTP address, which, when visited from a browser, prompts the user for a username and password. Entering the password shows me a simple HTML page: a directory of the files on this server.

**My question is this:** Is it possible to access this FTP address, supplying a username and password, through the pandas "read_json" aspect? The documentation on read_json states it can be supplied an address, but I'm not aware of a way to supply a full username and password to this FTP file address. My reasoning for trying to do it this way is that it's the simplest solution, but I'm guessing there's another way to do it that involves downloading the files separately, then feeding them to read_json.

The ultimate goal of this project is to have automatic daily pricing updates on a website. Our website shows prices for products, which are retrieved from a table on our MySQL Web server. The FTP address I've been provided is an updated-daily repository of those prices in JSON format. I'm basically learning Python for this project because it seemed like the right choice, but if anyone happens to have input on how I should be doing this project, I'd welcome the advice!

Comment: I would recommend using `requests` or `selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that a username and password can be passed as part of an address in read_json, like so:

```
df = pd.read_json('ftp://username:password@address.com/filepath/filename.txt')
```